# How to get the list item using REST API in c#

Tags: c#, api, rest, sharepoint-online

I want to retrieve all the list of SharePoint online using REST API in c#. 
For this, i am using below code

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://o365.sharepoint.com/sites/test-site/_api/web/lists");
endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.ContentLength = 0;
```

But i am getting below error

403:Forbidden Access denied. Before opening files in this location. you must first browse to the web site and select the option to login automatically.

So i have searched on this and found that we have to pass AuthenticationToken, which is written in this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx

```
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
```

But how do i get the accesstoken ?

Comment: You will have to obtain the AcceessToken from the Authentication Server (you will need valid credentials to do so)

Comment: I have valid credentials to do so, but how do i achieve Accesstoken. If you can provide sample code, that will be really helpful.

Comment: See this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth or
http://code.pearson.com/pearson-learningstudio/apis/authentication/authentication-sample-code/sample-code-oauth-2-c_x

Answer (score 0):

From [that same page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx#Anchor_2):

> […] It also assumes that you have a valid OAuth access token that is stored in the **accessToken** variable. You do not need the access token if you make this call from inside an add-in web, as you would in a SharePoint-hosted add-in. Note that you cannot obtain an access token from code that is running on a browser client. You must obtain the access token from code that is running on a server. [Context Token OAuth flow for SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142382.aspx) and [Authentication Code OAuth flow for SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj687470.aspx) explain how you can obtain an access token.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The application from which i am calling REST api, is not in SharePoint. So i need to write a code to get the accessToken from Authentication Server. If you can provide sample, that will be really helpful.